# Alternatives to "hangin' in there"

Tags: synonyms

My father uses this phrase WAY TOO MUCH!

Any suggestions to a more "engaging" way to view life?

Thanks

Comment: [Synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/get%20by)

Comment: What exactly do you want your alternative to mean? The imperative *Hang in there!* usually means *Don't give up!, Stick with it!* (strongly implying that the addressee's circumstances are already *not good*, and may even get worse before improving). Sometimes it's more "neutral", so *How am I doing? [I'm] Hangin' in there!* is more like *[I'm] getting by* (my circumstances aren't particularly good or bad, they're just "okay"). Or sometimes it's even "positive", as in *Stick to your guns!*, implying the addressee is well on the path to success. So what do you/your Dad want to imply?

Comment: Perhaps your father thinks you use "Way too much", way too much. Perhaps people you write to think you use capitals in an unnecessary manner. I could see their point.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the phrase "Living the dream", when asked how I am doing. I don't know if its a more "engaging" way to view life, but its a more positive way to view it. Also, its funnier.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost a non-sequitur, except in the sense of "Well I'll be a monkey's uncle", referring to evolution and the idea we came down from the trees.

I'd be interested in the origin of the phrase. (It has the feeling of something that comes from the comics, in that it becomes a joke with an connected visual representation.)

I might use any number of random phrases, possibly with more agency, as @conker suggests:

"Makin' it happen!"
"Doin' my thing!"

but a closer closer alternative might be

"*comme ci comme ça*" from the French
"samo samo" to connote "same as I was last time you asked"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is in the context of a response to a question similar to "*How are you doing?*", the response I often give is "**I'm still standing!**"

The other one I use, which may or may not apply in your father's case, is "**I'm old and tired.**"  If more explanation is needed, I'll add "**I got kids.**" (grammar error intended)  Actually, I use this so often that my mother-in-law got me a shirt that says that.

Answer (score 0):

similar phrases: 'Still coping', 'surviving',
when asked how one is: ' can't complain. '
when saying it in a way to encourage oneself: 'There's still fight left in me'
when asked if someone has given up on a job/ task: 'Trying my best to cope.' 'Doing my best to keep on track'            'Haven't given up yet.Still on it.'

'making lemonade out of what's left of the lemons? :]'